# Google Spreadsheet – Letter Grade Calculator and Variables

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Trying to create a **letter grade calculator** for personal use, however, I'm struggling with variables. "TOTAL" is the sum of all letter grades with their respective value. Please check the screenshot below.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVG8a.png)

Comment: Can you show what research you did till now? Do you have a formula you're working on? Consider providing a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on, free of sensitive information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the range with letters is in B23:B32 and the loopkup range is B24:E29, try in B33:

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B23:B32, D24:E29, 2, 0))))
```

and see if that works?

EDIT: For you locale, you may have to change the comma's to semi colons.

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B23:B32; D24:E29; 2; 0))))
```

Comment: Back i get: "Fel Fel i formeltolkning", which basically means there is something wrong with the formula.

Comment: That's one of the reasons, it is always very helpful to share a copy of the spreadsheet you are working with. ;-)

Comment: Perfect! Just one tiny problem: how do I change the output to numbers instead of the actual formula. Right now I have to hover over to see the sum.